# How do I make a new concatenated column?

Tags: python

I have a .csv that has data like this:

```
30,972.74176,0.446378,1.825426,cl+l  
31,1015.075579,0.279686,2.950118,l  
32,1072.59334,0.273239,4.408458,cl+l  
33,1139.55317,-1.616904,4.756378,l  
34,1279.86304,50.335186,3.877577,r  
35,1181.541419,61.399389,5.155133,r  
36,1097.421199,63.809733,5.37508,r  
37,1018.555678,64.034432,2.59232,r
```

I have written a program that takes out the rows where the last column (E, as I am calling it in my program) is either an "l" or "cl+l" and copies it to another file called "left.csv".  What I want to do is add another column to left.csv that takes the data from the second column (B), put a comma in between them, and then the data from column D.

So, left.csv right now looks like:

```
30,972.74176,0.446378,1.825426,cl+l  
31,1015.075579,0.279686,2.950118,l  
32,1072.59334,0.273239,4.408458,cl+l  
33,1139.55317,-1.616904,4.756378,l
```

What I want is:

```
30,972.74176,0.446378,1.825426,cl+l,"972.74176,1.825426"  
31,1015.075579,0.279686,2.950118,l,"1015.075579,2.950118"    
32,1072.59334,0.273239,4.408458,cl+l,"1072.59334,4.408458"   
33,1139.55317,-1.616904,4.756378,l,"1139.55317,4.756378"
```

How should I go about achieving this, and how can I tell the program that the comma should not start the next entry even though it's csv?  Is that possible, and will I have to have the parentheses or a different delimiter maybe?  The code I have right now is:

```
import csv
import sys
import operator

fieldnames = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
surveyfile = open("source.csv", "r")
left_file = open("left.csv",'wb')
right_file = open("right.csv",'wb')
coil_file = open("coil1.csv","wb")


reader = csv.DictReader(surveyfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=",")
left_writer = csv.DictWriter(left_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
sortedlefts = sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]))

surveyfile.seek(0,0)

right_writer = csv.DictWriter(right_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
sortedrights = sorted(reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]), reverse=True)

coil_writer = csv.DictWriter(coil_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",")

for row in sortedlefts:
    if row["E"] == "l" or row["E"] == "cl+l":
        left_writer.writerow(row)
        coil_writer.writerow(row)   


for row in sortedrights:
    if row["E"] == "r":
        right_writer.writerow(row)
        coil_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an extra value to `row`, formatted to include the comma:

```
row['F'] = '%s,%s' % (row['E'], row['B'])
```

or use `','.join()`:

```
row['F'] = ','.join([row['E'], row['B']])
```

but do include `'F'` in your fields for `left_writer`:

```
left_writer = csv.DictWriter(left_file, fieldnames + ['F'], delimiter=",")
```

If you configure your `coil_writer` instance to *ignore* extra columns, you don't need to create a separate loop for it or create a copy of `row` in your existing loop:

```
coil_writer = csv.DictWriter(coil_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",", extrasaction='ignore')
```

The csv writer will take care of the quoting for you.

Comment: When I add that inside the for loop, I keep getting: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'.  Also, I want to append only left.csv, not both.  Will I have to make a seperate for loop for coil_writer then?

Comment: @user1879422: updated (didn't realize it was a dictwriter at first).